# Batch file extract and pass text into variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have text file Ex. c:\sample.txt which contains two tag only

```
<jid>JURO</aid>
<aid>12345</aid>
```

By using batch file remove that tag and assign to variable.
    %aid%=JURO
    %jid%=12345

I am tried with findstr command but i'am unable to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<>" %%i in (c:\sample.txt) do set "%%i=%%j"
```

the chars `>` and `<` are used as delimiters, so first token is the first tag (jid), second token is the value (and third token would be `/aid` - but we don't use it here

Comment: @Kathirvtv - It would be helpful if you would mark this as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark.